# How do I tell if imported jerky is parasite-free?

Tags: beef, jerky

Recently bought a pack of beef jerky (it is a rather rare find in my country). While I have bought jerky before, those were produced in EU, but this packet is originating from Brazil and - I don't want to offend anyone - Brazil has much lower food safety standard than the EU.
Are there any real concerns regarding parasite infections or am I just exaggerating? This is a commercial product, properly imported to my country.
Is it a good idea to put the packet in the freezer for a few days?

Comment: That's a very different question from the OP.

Comment: @FuzzyChef maybe... Perhaps mods can edit one of the questions or combine the two.  For site organizational purposes, it makes little sense to have two questions with essentially the same title question.

Comment: Folks could also suggest and edit to the title instead of voting to close it.  It's pretty new-asker-hostile when folks close a question without even reading the actual question.

Comment: Apologies, @Moha, you're a victim of "close first, read second".

Comment: I am trying to understand why people think that this would not be a duplicate. Moha, are you asking whether food imported into the EU is legally required to meet the same food safety standards as food produced within the EU? Or is it that you are expecting us to pronounce a general "it's safe" or "it's unsafe" verdict, or give a probability of contamination? The second desire is understandable, but impossible. There is no such thing as knowing the risk that comes from a given food. The best approximation is the binary "meets the standards"/"doesn't meet the standards" - but there is no ...

Comment: ... "higher" authority to which to compare food standards and declare that "food which meets standard X is *really* safe" and "food which only meets standard Y is not really safe". It is up to you, personally, to decide whether you trust a given standard, or not, there is no objective way to make such a decision. In that sense, we cannot answer a generic question. If you wish to reopen, we could rewrite the question to the first suggestion - whether the EU allows imported food to be produced by the producing country's standards, or requires its own standards to be met.

Answer (score 2):

If a food product is manufactured for export to a country with food safety guides , it *should* be safe for consumption.

The product must kinda  satisfy the local food safety rules it will not be imported, or, same thing for every other food product will be recalled if some issue is found on the product.